# Import error: No module named Include in Python Django

Tags: python, django

The Python version is 2.7. When I run the below command

```
(test) C:\virtualenvs\test> python manage.py runserver
```

under a virtual environment I get an error saying:

```
File "C:\virtualenvs\test\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
Module = import_module(entry)
File "c:\python27\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 37, in import_module__import__(name)
ImportError: no module named Include
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you running it from your virtualenv directory?

Comment: Do by chance have the line `import Include` in a `urls.py` file instead of `from django.conf.urls import include`? Even if it is not in `urls.py` you should search your project for `import Include` and make sure that is really want you want to do or change if it is not. Also, Please show your full error.

Comment: @postelrich Because the application is inside the test dir which is a virtualenv directory. Do you mean that I don't have to put my application code inside a virtualenv dir? I can put that code anywhere?

Comment: Yea the virtualenv is only for managing your environment, isolated set of python packages for your project.  Your project should be in a separate directory as virtualenv takes care of adding those packages to the pythonpath.

Comment: @postelrich I was thinking about this before butthen got diverted to something else. I will try this once I am in home. I will let you know the feedback.

Comment: It's fixed. I run the app from a different location. Thanks @postelrich for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You have not provided any code, if I was to assume, then I would say you haven't imported `include` in your urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include
```

Add the above in your urls.py and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was running py code from a virtual directory. It's fixed now.